# Python - regroup list of dictionaries into two nested list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries which contain matching sites and matching devices, I would like to regroup those dictionaries by site and then by device.

I have added a sample output dictionary and a desired dictionary.

I thought I could use itertools to do multiple groups which has worked I do have the groups but I'm unsure how to merge it all or if this is the most efficient method

itertools attempt:

```
site_groups = itertools.groupby(bgp_data_query, lambda i: i['location'])
for key, site in site_groups:
    device_groups = itertools.groupby(site, lambda i: i['device_name'])
    for key, device in site_groups:
```

raw data

```
[
    {
        "bgp_peer_as": "1",
        "bgp_session": "3:35",
        "bgp_routes": "0",
        "service_status": "Down",
        "location": "London",
        "circuit_name": "MPLS",
        "device_name": "LON-EDGE",
        "timestamp" : "2019-5-8 12:30:00"
    },
    {
        "bgp_peer_as": "3",
        "bgp_session": "4:25",
        "bgp_routes": "100",
        "service_status": "UP",
        "location": "London",
        "circuit_name": "MPLS 02",
        "device_name": "LON-EDGE",
        "timestamp" : "2019-5-8 12:30:00"
    },    
    {
        "bgp_peer_as": "18",
        "bgp_session": "1:25",
        "bgp_routes": "1",
        "service_status": "UP",
        "location": "London",
        "circuit_name": "INTERNET",
        "device_name": "LON-INT-GW",
        "timestamp" : "2019-5-8 12:31:00"
    },  
    {
        "bgp_peer_as": "20",
        "bgp_session": "1:25",
        "bgp_routes": "1",
        "service_status": "UP",
        "location": "Manchester",
        "circuit_name": "INTERNET",
        "device_name": "MAN-INT-GW",
        "timestamp" : "2019-5-8 12:20:00"
    },     
    {
        "bgp_peer_as": "20",
        "bgp_session": "1:25",
        "bgp_routes": "1",
        "service_status": "UP",
        "location": "Manchester",
        "circuit_name": "INTERNET 02",
        "device_name": "MAN-INT-GW",
        "timestamp" : "2019-5-8 12:20:00"
    }, 
    {
        "bgp_peer_as": "45",
        "bgp_session": "1:25",
        "bgp_routes": "1",
        "service_status": "UP",
        "location": "Manchester",
        "circuit_name": "MPLS 01",
        "device_name": "MAN-EDGE",
        "timestamp" : "2019-5-8 12:21:00"
    },             
]
```

desired dict

```
[
    { 
    "London": { 
        "LON-EDGE": {
            "bgp_peer_as": "1",
            "bgp_session": "3:35",
            "bgp_routes": "0",
            "service_status": "DOWN",
            "circuit_name": "MPLS",
            },
            {
            "bgp_peer_as": "1",
            "bgp_session": "4:25",
            "bgp_routes": "100",
            "service_status": "UP",
            "circuit_name": "MPLS 02",
            }
        },
        { 
        "LON-INT-GW" : {
            "bgp_peer_as": "18",
            "bgp_session": "1:25",
            "bgp_routes": "1",
            "service_status": "UP",
            "circuit_name": "INTERNET",
            }
        }
    }
],
[
    { 
    "Manchester": { 
        "MAN-EDGE": {
            "bgp_peer_as": "45",
            "bgp_session": "1:25",
            "bgp_routes": "1",
            "service_status": "UP",
            "circuit_name": "MPLS 01",
            }
        },
        {
        "MAN-INT-GW": {
            "bgp_peer_as": "20",
            "bgp_session": "1:25",
            "bgp_routes": "1",
            "service_status": "UP",
            "circuit_name": "INTERNET",
            },
            {
            "bgp_peer_as": "20",
            "bgp_session": "1:25",
            "bgp_routes": "1",
            "service_status": "UP",
            "circuit_name": "INTERNET 02",
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Ignoring the variable name mistakes in your code, beware that `groupby` requires the items to be sorted by the key first.

Comment: `pandas` will help you here. try `pd.DataFrame(bgp_data_query).groupby(['location', 'device_name'])`

Comment: your desired dict is a syntax error. deep inside there are sets of dicts.

Comment: lve probably formatted the desired output incorrectly but hopefully what im trying to achieve is understandable? location > device > service 1, service 2 etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a double `collections.defaultdict` with a list at the deepest level for this, and loop on the items, popping the "keys" so they don't appear in the final data:

```
result = collections.defaultdict(lambda :collections.defaultdict(list))

for d in raw_dict:
    location = d.pop("location")
    device_name = d.pop("device_name")
    result[location][device_name].append(d)
```

result with your data (dumped as `json` to get rid of the representation of the special dicts):

```
import json
print(json.dumps(result,indent=4))

{
    "Manchester": {
        "MAN-INT-GW": [
            {
                "bgp_routes": "1",
                "service_status": "UP",
                "bgp_peer_as": "20",
                "circuit_name": "INTERNET",
                "bgp_session": "1:25"
            },
            {
                "bgp_routes": "1",
                "service_status": "UP",
                "bgp_peer_as": "20",
                "circuit_name": "INTERNET 02",
                "bgp_session": "1:25"
            }
        ],
        "MAN-EDGE": [
            {
                "bgp_routes": "1",
                "service_status": "UP",
                "bgp_peer_as": "45",
                "circuit_name": "MPLS 01",
                "bgp_session": "1:25"
            }
        ]
    },
    "London": {
        "LON-EDGE": [
            {
                "bgp_routes": "0",
                "service_status": "Down",
                "bgp_peer_as": "1",
                "circuit_name": "MPLS",
                "bgp_session": "3:35"
            },
            {
                "bgp_routes": "100",
                "service_status": "UP",
                "bgp_peer_as": "3",
                "circuit_name": "MPLS 02",
                "bgp_session": "4:25"
            }
        ],
        "LON-INT-GW": [
            {
                "bgp_routes": "1",
                "service_status": "UP",
                "bgp_peer_as": "18",
                "circuit_name": "INTERNET",
                "bgp_session": "1:25"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

note that `itertools.groupby`-based solutions also work, but only when identical keys are *contiguous*. Else it creates several groups, not what you want.

Comment: thanks, is there a way to return it into JSON loads? right now im doing bgp_data_json = json.dumps(result,indent=4)
bgp_data = json.loads(bgp_data_json)

Comment: also one more, is it possible to add the timestamp into the device dictionary (all timestamps are the same per device) so it would be {London: {LON-EDGE: [listofpeers],timestamp: 2019-5-8 12:30:00"},...

Comment: "return it into JSON loads" ? you mean get rid of the dict specialities? no need those are dictionaries all right. I did that just to be able to display it properly.  no need for json serialization/deserialization.

Comment: "is it possible to add the timestamp into the device dictionary": yes. Iterate on the values, add a key to the dict value.

Answer (score 1):

Can use `defaultdict` along with `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict
res = defaultdict(dict)

for x, g in itertools.groupby(bgp_data_query, key=lambda x: x["location"]):
    for d, f in itertools.groupby(g, key=lambda x: x["device_name"]):
        res[x][d] = [{k:v}  for z in f for k, v in z.items() if k not in {"location", "device_name"}]

print(dict(res))
```

Output:

```
{'London': {'LON-EDGE': [{'bgp_peer_as': '1'},
   {'bgp_routes': '0'},
   {'circuit_name': 'MPLS'},
   {'bgp_session': '3:35'},
   {'service_status': 'Down'},
   {'bgp_peer_as': '3'},
   {'bgp_routes': '100'},
   {'circuit_name': 'MPLS 02'},
   {'bgp_session': '4:25'},
   {'service_status': 'UP'}],
  'LON-INT-GW': [{'bgp_peer_as': '18'},
   {'bgp_routes': '1'},
   {'circuit_name': 'INTERNET'},
   {'bgp_session': '1:25'},
   {'service_status': 'UP'}]},
 'Manchester': {'MAN-EDGE': [{'bgp_peer_as': '45'},
   {'bgp_routes': '1'},
   {'circuit_name': 'MPLS 01'},
   {'bgp_session': '1:25'},
   {'service_status': 'UP'}],
  'MAN-INT-GW': [{'bgp_peer_as': '20'},
   {'bgp_routes': '1'},
   {'circuit_name': 'INTERNET'},
   {'bgp_session': '1:25'},
   {'service_status': 'UP'},
   {'bgp_peer_as': '20'},
   {'bgp_routes': '1'},
   {'circuit_name': 'INTERNET 02'},
   {'bgp_session': '1:25'},
   {'service_status': 'UP'}]}}
```